# Changing scale of mesh changes lighting brightness of scene?

Tags: three.js

I needed to refactor my custom mesh creation a bit 
from:
create mesh of unified sizes (SIZE,SIZE,SIZE), than scale them as needed (setting scale for each axis)
to:
create mesh with correct size, do not scale later

meshes are custom generated (vertices, faces, normals, uvs), nothing of this process was altered, worked like a charm before

=> resulting meshes are the same size, position, etc.

The whole scene setup stays the same: lights, shadowing, materials, yet when using the second approach the whole lighting is very very bright and super reflective, is that a known issue?

material used is MeshPhongMaterial with map, bumMap, specMap, envMap

using three.js r68, no error/warning in console

before:
https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/3647854/3876053/76b8f260-2158-11e4-9e96-c8de55eaec9a.png

after:
https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/3647854/3876052/76b7fa86-2158-11e4-9393-8f3eece04c0b.png

Answer (score 1):

Did you rescale the normals in the mesh?

The mesh format probably needs normalized normals, in which case, the new normals are now incorrect, but would've been correct, if you hadn't rescaled.

Alternately, you say the lights haven't been changed, maybe they need to be appropriately redirected in the scene. (Assuming you're applying different scaling factors in each axis.)

Comment: normals are generated when the mesh is generated: `//normals
  geometry.computeFaceNormals();
  geometry.computeVertexNormals();` so I guess, they should be normalized, does this need to be renormalized in any way when calling basic `mesh.scale.set(x,y,z)`? scaling is only applied to meshes, lights are fixed in scene, is that a problem, isn't lighting computed in pixel shader of the `MeshPhongMaterial` thus effectively having the vertices (and pixels) already in correct places?